# How to replace previous set of elements after sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that has a set of unsorted values and would like to sort those values alphabetically by textContent in descending order.  Though the elements, 'defaultValues', are showing as sorted when I do a console log, the replaceWith is not updating the dom.  How can I replace the unsorted elements with the sorted?

```
function sortDefaultValues() {
    rows = tbody.find('tr');
    rows.each(function(i, row) {
        var tableCell = $(row).find('td')[3];
        var defaultValues = $(tableCell).find('span div.custom-label').clone();
        defaultValues.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a.textContent.localeCompare(b.textContent);
        });
        var oldDefaultValues = $(tableCell).find('span div.single-value').parent();

        $(oldDefaultValues).replaceWith($(defaultValues).parent());
    });
}
```

I would expect the replaceWith call to update the DOM with the sorted elements, but the order is remaining the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
$(oldDefaultValues).replaceWith($(defaultValues).parent());
```

to this:

```
$(oldDefaultValues).replaceWith(defaultValues);
```

the var `defaultValues` is a clone of `tableCell`, and when you specifiy `$(defaultValues).parent();`, you are actually referencing the original unsorted table.

Also, I always use [sorttable](https://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/) for table sorting, but I'm not sure if this would be helpful in your exact situation.